# Is standarization necessary for ridge regression?

Tags: regression, ridge-regression

Is variable normalization necessary in Ridge regression (for both X and y)? If so, what happens (mathematically) if we don't do it?

Comment: if you don't do it, you are penalizing variables that are on different scales differently. So because 1 percent point increase for, say, percent employment is very different from 1 dollar increase in GDP, using the same penalty for each of dimensions would penalize the coefficient for percentages much more than GDP (which can be small because GDP itself is big).

Comment: See the references I gave in a comment to your other recent question on RR.